# Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter

Tags: wifi

I  have my Windows 7 and all was working fine, and a samsung duos phone. i cant connect my phone to my hostednetwork coz it says 'no internet access'

netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=name key=name
netsh wlan start hostednetwork

i use this command i created virtual wi-fi successfully with "no internet access" ...

I already tried editing the services.msc 
application layer gateway service - automatic
network connections - automatic
Network Location Awareness (NLA) - automatic
Plug And Play - automatic
Remote Access Auto Connection Manager - automatic
Remote Access Connection Manager - automatic
Remote Procedure Call (RPC) - automatic
Telephony - automatic

Still no internet access

can any one help me...!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can find it yourself via [Google](https://www.google.com) easily!

You need to share a working internet connection to the Virtual Lan Adaptor Created by Adaptor to provide you internet access virtually. Additionally, if there are DNS failures, then you might as well need to configure manual IP and respective subnet.

For ease; visit [this page](http://www.talkofweb.com/creating-wi-fi-hotspot-in-windows-8-share-laptop-internet-connection/)

Hope it helps.